# What is the quickest way in Oracle SQL to find out if one or more duplicates exist in a table?

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates

I'm looking to create a statement that stops and returns true the very second it finds a duplicate value on a column. I don't care what the value is and simply need to know whether a duplicate exists or not; nothing else.

I know i can write `Select count(*) from myTable group by primary_id having count(*) > 1;` but this goes through every single row of the table, whereas I want the query to stop as soon as it encounters a single case of a duplicate existing.

The best shot i've attempted with what i know is this:-

```
 select 1 as thingy from dual outer_qry
 where exists
 (
    select * from
      (
       select some_ID, 
              case when COUNT(*) > 1 then 'X' else 'N' end as TRIG 
       from myTable 
       group by some_ID
       )INNER_QRY
       where INNER_QRY.trig = outer_qry.dummy 
 );
```

However this takes 13 seconds and I doubt it takes that long to find the first duplicate.

Can anyone please suggest where my thinking is going wrong as, hopefully from my SQL, my assumption is that the EXISTS function will be checked for every row returned for the inner_qry, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would use `exists`.  This returns all the duplicates:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where exists (select 1
              from mytable t t2
              where t2.some_id = t.some_id and t2.rowid <> t.rowid
             );
```

In Oracle 12c, you would add `fetch first 1 row only`.  And it can take advantage of an index on `mytable(some_id)`.

In earlier versions:

```
select 1 as HasDuplicate
from (select t.*
      from mytable t
      where exists (select 1
                    from mytable t t2
                    where t2.some_id = t.some_id and t2.rowid <> t.rowid
                   )
     ) t
where rownum = 1;
```

If this returns no rows, then there are no duplicates.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to read this properly and understand the problem before offering a solution. Works perfectly (y)

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from table1 t1 natural join table1 t2 where t1.rowid < t2.rowid;
```

Comment: How can a solution with an join be faster than `GROUP BY` and `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this to understand which `id` is dublicate

```
   select some_ID 
   from myTable 
   group by some_ID having count(*) >1
```

Comment: I explain in the question that this is not what i'm looking for.